# iOS Multitasking: Reductions performed by system upon entering background

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

I've watched the WWDC 2010 talks about adopting multitasking and I have started enabling our app, however I have a question regarding releasing non-visible views.

According to the talk (Session 105 - Adopting Multitasking on iPhone OS, Part 1 - 00:34:50) it is stated that the system releases "non-visible UIViewController views" when entering the background. However during my testing (in the simulator), I'm not seeing this happen.

The `-viewDidUnload` methods aren't being called, and after entering the foreground and viewing a previously hidden VC, the `-loadView` method is not being called either. So the hidden VC views in my UITabBarController aren't being released at all, contrary to what they said in the talk. Any ideas?

There's no mention of this in the "[Moving to the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW21)" documentation, only in the talk.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simulating a memory warning while your app is in the background?  I believe that the views are only released when other apps start requesting memory.  If memory consumption stays the same, your views are not released so that you can switch back quicker.

Comment: Interesting! Triggering memory warnings while in the background does cause `-viewDidUnload` to be called once the app re-enters the foreground. So my only question is, does the system trigger these warnings (during a low memory situation) before it starts looking at terminating apps? These un-needed views are taking up memory and counting towards the "dirty size" measure that iOS will look at.

Comment: Yes, the warnings happen before apps are terminated.  I believe there are at least two different levels that you are notified of.  I think three total levels.  Though I can't find the doc explaining it at the moment.